# How can I integrate sms api in Contact7 form in wordpress

Tags: sms

I have taken SMS service from http://bulksmsindia.mobi/bulksmsindia/index.html. I want to integrate SMS in my WordPress website as a confirmation form submission. I have got from the service provider below but how can I integrate please guide.

Bulk SMS India Developers API

HTTP API Details

Send SMS(Comma Seperated):

```
http://bulksmsindia.mobi/sendurlcomma.aspx?user=profileid&pwd=password&senderid=ABC&mobileno=9999999989,9999999990,9999999991&msgtext=Hello
```

Code Sample:(Send SMS)

```
''''write code for loop while (you can open record set here)
 sResponse = ""
 sResponse = SMSSend(pno, message )
 If right(sResponse,15) = "Send Successful" Then
 'write your code here
 End If
 '''End Wend
 Function SMSSend (strPh,strMsg)

 Dim msgResponse
 Dim strRequest
 Dim strUrl
 msgResponse = ""

 strPh=right(strPh,10)
 If not IsNumeric(strPh) Or len(strPh) <> 10 Then
 msgResponse = "Enter valid Mobile Number."
 End If
 If strMsg = "" Then
 msgResponse = "Enter text message."
 End If

 strUrl = "http://bulksmsindia.mobi/sendurlcomma.asp?"
 strRequest = strRequest+"&user=profileid"
 strRequest = strRequest+"&pwd=pass"
 strRequest = strRequest+"&senderid=senderid"
 strRequest = strRequest+"&mobileno="+strPh
 strRequest = strRequest+"&msgtext="+Server.URLEncode(strMsg)

 strUrl = strUrl+strRequest

 If msgResponse = "" Then
 Dim oXML
 Dim sPage
 Err.Clear
 On Error Resume Next
 Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
 oXML.Open "get", strUrl , false
 oXML.Send
 msgResponse = oXML.ResponseText
 Set oXML = Nothing
 End If

 SMSSend = msgResponse

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 SMSSend = "Problem on sending sms : "& Err.Description
 End If

 End Function
```

Comment: Your sample code is just VBA to make a GET request to that URL, which you can do with wp_remote_get() in WordPress. I don't know CF7 well enough to tell you which action you should hook, nor can I see the hooks in the CF7 documentation (!) but here's a third-party list: http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/5.1.7/hooks/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to integrate SMS into Contact Form 7 is to find an SMS provider that supports an email interface to send the SMS.

Then just tick Mail 2 at the bottom of the config form and you can put your message into that.

I've done this in the past with Kapow SMS gateway.